# Merge legend from different geom and aes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, legend

the idea is simple:
(1)Use red dot for actual data;
(2)Use blue dashed line for fitted value.
But I just could not find a way to make such legend.

My fig and code below:
[image: fig]

```
library(ggplot)
x <- seq(1,100,1)
y <- 2*x + runif(100,-5,5)
fit_y <- 2*x

df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y,fit_y=fit_y)
df

ggplot(df)+
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color='point', shape='point'))+
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=fit_y, color='line', linetype='line')) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('point'='red', 'line'='blue')) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('line'='longdash')) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c('point'=1 ))
```

And I am pretty confused about that: Why is color legend composed of line and point?
Now it is a "blue line + blue point" PLUS "red line + red point".
But I only assign red to geom_point and blue to geom_line! Why is this?

Comment: Try: `ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y), color='blue') + geom_line(aes(x=x, y=fit_y), color='red', linetype='longdash')` ?

Comment: No legend showing this way...(Maybe because no attributes in aes() mapping)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the best way is to not bother mapping aesthetics for shape and linetype at all, and instead overriding the display of the colour legend directly. This is also the [suggested](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3648#issue-530627481) workaround for guides indiscriminately applying glyphs for every key.

```r
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(1,100,1)
y <- 2*x + runif(100,-5,5)
fit_y <- 2*x

df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y,fit_y=fit_y)

ggplot(df)+
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color='point'),
             shape = 1)+
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=fit_y, color='line', linetype='line'),
            linetype = 'longdash') +
  scale_color_manual(
    values=c('point'='red', 'line'='blue'),
    guide = guide_legend(
      override.aes = list(
        shape = c(1, NA),
        linetype = c(NA, 5)
      )
    )
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Wow, this is smarter than the answer below. And I find this post(https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/07/controlling-legend-appearance-in-ggplot2-with-override-aes/) for who has same problem

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you want your data to be blue dots and your fitted value to be red dashed line.

I tried to make some adjustments on your code like following:

```
ggplot(df)+
geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color='point', shape='point'))+
geom_line(aes(x=x, y=fit_y, color='line', linetype='line')) +
scale_color_manual(values=c('point'='blue', 'line'='red')) +
scale_linetype_manual(values = c('line'='longdash')) +
scale_shape_manual(values = c('point'=1 ))
```

And so that I got following graph:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DI50.png)

Comment: Sorry I mistyped, I know how to plot the geom But don't know how to make the legend

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for?

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color="real"), shape=1)+
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=fit_y, linetype="estimate"), color="blue") +
  scale_color_manual(name="", values=c(real="red")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name="", values = c(estimate="longdash")) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

The issue is that they are not really combined, they are still two separate legends, which is why I add the legend at the bottom, it looks more like one legend

Comment: Thanks! So this is a legend for 'color' and one for 'linetype'.  Is there a way to combine multiple aes in one legend? But this works too, thank u